# bash/expect script that continues if password provided is correct

Tags: linux, bash, expect

i'm not used to use expect in a bash script, anyway what i'm trying to achieve is a bash script that when a password is asked, it will check if the connection is correct to a remote machine, then if correct to execute some commands remotely, then exit

until now i managed to put the expect in a variable for the checks( i know it's pretty ugly):

```
SCRIPT1=$(expect -c "

spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST

expect \"assword:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect \"\\\\$\"
send \"show \/SP\/clock\r\"
expect -re \"$USER.*\"
send \"exit\r\"
")

echo "$SCRIPT1"
```

is there a way to implement the password check in a bash script?

EDIT: public-key auth in not an option in this case, sorry

Comment: Why not just run `ssh` directly, and let it prompt the user for the password?

Comment: Skip the password, and set up public-key authentication.

Comment: embedding Expect in shell scripts is tricky. take a look at my [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect/)

Comment: And if you're going to trust every host anyway ( `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` ) why don't just use telnet? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the fact is that once the status is ok and expect is "correctly escaped", it will work (not sure if it will be useful to somebody in the future)...

```
echo "Enter the Remote Password:"
read -s PASS
echo "Verifying password..."
CHECK=$(expect -c "

spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${u}@${H}

expect \"assword:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect {
        \"\\\\$\" {exit 0}
        \"assword:\" { exit 1}
}
expect -re \"${u}.*\"
send \"exit\r\"
")


if [ $? == 1 ]
then
echo "Password validation failed. Please execute again with correct password for the ILOM and user selected. Exiting..."
exit
else
echo "Password validation correct..."
```